# Rails: Model that references one of a list of potential other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm building a rails application that allows users to call one of many web services with user-defined credentials that are saved in an instance of the service type. The user will create an instance of the Service model, that has_one instance of another model (that defines the service type). Where it gets tricky is that there are different service types. So the Service instance needs to link to one of many different possible models, but I'm not sure how to do this.

For example the Service model, which belongs to a user, will have a has_one reference to only one of the following classes:

- ServiceType1
- ServiceType2
- ServiceType3

I want to know how I could have a reference field with model as an optional field.

Would the following work?:

- Service.reference - has an ID of the ServiceTypeX instance
- Service.serviceType - selects the correct ServiceTypeX model

Or could it be managed somehow with a has_one through relation?

I want to allow many different service types in the future, so having a reference field for each would not be the best approach.

Apologies in advance for unclear explanation... it's very hard to clearly explain.

Comment: This sounds like a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) to me.

Comment: Reading up on it now, it looks like it could be the right solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to spickermann for the comment. Polymorphic Association did the trick!

This is what I did:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :serviceable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end

module ServiceTypes
  class ServiceType1 < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :service, as: :serviceable
  end
end
```